# What is the longest stretch of Babylonian Talmud with neither Ravina nor Rav Ashi?

Tags: talmud-bavli

What is the longest stretch of Babylonian Talmud with neither Ravina nor Rav Ashi? I heard it was 3 pages.

Answer (score 9):

Neither of them appear between Tamid 28a and Niddah 8a, which is also a stretch of **11 daf**. If you count Maseches Middos, which, although it has no Gemara, is printed in-line with the pages of the Vilna Shas, you get a stretch of **15 daf**.

Comment: Is Middos considered Gemorrah?

Answer (score 8):

Neither of them appear between [Nedarim](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l33.htm) 35 and 48; so you can go **eleven** pages without them.

This is the longest such stretch; many other stretches of length > 3 exist.

Comment: I like your answer better than Yosef's since yours remains in a single masechta yet contains the same amount of blatt.